# reasons for paypal 10544 Gateway Decline error

Tags: paypal

Hi 
    Can you please give me the possible reasons for pay pal DoDirectPayment 10544 Gateway Decline error. I have searched a lot I couldn't find the reasons for it.

Answer (score 3):

First the obligatory "stupid human trick" question: Are you sure that the card you're using is a valid credit card? If you're in live (as opposed to sandbox), the sample card numbers they give will no longer work, and you must use a real credit card.

With that out of the way, is the account setup for DoDirectPayment? Do you have a certificate? If you're sure everything is setup properly and you're still receiving the error, try posting the actual API request here so we can take a look at your problem.

Comment: Thanks Fibericon for your valuable reply.I was testing with the sample credit card numbers such as(4111111111111111). Now I understood the problem.