# Reasons for PayPal error 10544: Please use a different credit card

Tags: paypal

NOTE: I've already looked at [reasons for paypal 10544 Gateway Decline error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688523/reasons-for-paypal-10544-gateway-decline-error). This is happening in production for us.

We use DoDirectPayment and DoReferenceTransaction with our customers to set up a regular payment transactions and when we get failures, the vast majority of them are for this error code. I've asked for details for specific transactions before and was instructed to get our client to contact PayPal directly for security reasons, which is understandable.

But I was wondering if there was something more to this particular error than the rather vague description implies. E.g. is there some setting in the account settings that causes it to occur more often than it needs to? Is it because we are a Canadian merchant accepting credit cards from other currencies?

We don't really like asking our customers to contact PayPal about this because it feels like we're passing the buck.

Comment: please share some of your code with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a lot more specific reason for this error, it is vague due to the number of reasons that can cause this.  Usually this is due to an issue with the buyers account or card, in which case the buyer would need to contact PayPal to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This  is a catch-all for a variety of messages that unfortunately aren't spelled out in the [Payflow  Gateway Developers Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf) but do appear here [Classic API Error Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/) with a vague explanation of:

> The transaction was declined by PayPal. Contact PayPal for more information.

We recently switched to Paypal from Paymentech (but still using Payflow Gateway). About 15 of our customers with monthly service billings began getting declined.  These were all customers whose credit cards were approved for years on Paymentech.

Paypal told us that (for security reasons) the customer had to call Paypal directly for more information.  One of our customers did that and reported that Paypal couldn't tell them what was up so they lifted the "ban" on that card.  Another customer reported that Paypal support couldn't understand that this was a problem with a Merchant account, not a Personal.  Yet another left us for the competition.

In the end, I wrote code to trap for this error and print the following message on our commerce site and email notification:

> Our payment processor, PayPal, was unable to process your credit card. Please try a different card, or contact PayPal Support at 888.221.1161 to determine why your credit card wasn't accepted.

Furthermore, I've ask that this be escalated within Paypal because this is bit of a hack.